# SQL Server high logins/sec

Tags: sql-server

We noticed some occasional problem with response of our SQL Server 2012 STD R2. 
Mostly, it works just fine, with stable performance numbers:

- arround 100 user connections
- logins/sec: between 0 and 2
- logouts/sec: between 0 and 2

Therefore I believe SQL Server works fine, and connection pooling works fine, too.

However, occasionally we observe strange data:

- logins/sec rise above 10/sec
- logouts/sec still between 0 and 2/sec
- user connestions rise up to 1000
- CPU rise up to 100%

...therefore we have very slow response time.

I must add, that it happens last 3 days only, with the same load on server.

How could we locate the reason for that behavior?
Could it be DDOS?

Comment: What type of application do you have connecting to SQL Server?

Comment: Have you checked if there has been deadlocks?

Comment: This needs to be moved to the DBA forum--this is not a development question.

Comment: No, there wasn't any deadlock.

Comment: We have classic ASP with SQLNCLI11 conn.string + SQL authentication.

Comment: It doesn't _need_ to be moved there... iirc, dba-ish questions are also welcomed here. However, it will probably find a better audience there. It's in the OP's best interests to ask there instead.

Comment: Perhaps your application is the target of a [DoS attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack)?

Comment: You could check *IIS* logs, and check how you are setting up the connection string, since even a change in the *casing* can effect the connection pool.

Answer (score 0):

you could use sql server profiler or xevents to capture the login info, you could look in SQL errorlog to see if IP addresses are being logged, you could check windows event log for system apps/processes also connecting to SQL.